# unable to come up with htaccess rewrite engine

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect domain1.com to domain2.com in all cases except one particular case:

```
domain1.com/subfolder/index.php
```

I want this domain1.com/subfolder/index.php to be intact and not get redirected to domain2.com because I have hundreds of users already bookmarked this page.

But anything and everything besides that domain1.com/subfolder/index.php, I want domain1.com to be redirected to domain2.com

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RewriteCond to check to see the requested uri is anything but the one you want to redirect, capture the desired path and then redirect to the second domain.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/index.php$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain2.com/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the following `.htaccess` in your web root `/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

- Use just `[L]` if you want the redirection to be transparent i.e. without letting your visitors know.
- Use `!^/subfolder/.*$` if you want to stop redirection for the complete folder as well as its contents.